# File.ReadAllText(String) reads cyrillic/Russian chars as?

Tags: c#, encoding

1. I created a vb file using File.WriteAllText(String, String), which creates a file with UTF-8 encoding without BOM.
2. and inserted some cyrillic(Russian) chars to this file from VS (VSTA). while saving the file

   - In some servers, displays File conversion dialog.
   - In some servers,
     automatically converts the file to "UCS-2 little endian" without
     showing the file conversion dialog.
   - In some servers, not showing file
     conversion dialog. But when I read the file again using
     File.ReadAllText(String), it reads russian chars as ???

why?

Comment: UTF-8 supports Cyrillic characters. For example, in case it doesn't show file conversion dialog, and assuming that your file is still UTF-8, it cannot read Russian chars inproperly.

Comment: Because without the BOM, there is no way to detect the encoding. That's the whole purpose of the BOM (even if there are some drawbacks, less and less nowadays)

Comment: if so, the issue should be consistent. how it is working one server, and showing ?? in other server?